# "Try to" or "try verbing" in this case

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> I tried ****to order/ordering**** a book on line  but I did not succeed.

I think "to order" is better

I know the difference between "try to" or "try verbing" ("try to" means we made an effort but he did not work) ("try verbing" means try another way to do it to solve the situation) so the first seems better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [try+gerund/infinitive (Difference in meaning)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44160/trygerund-infinitive-difference-in-meaning)

Comment: also a duplicate of [Should the verb try be followed by gerund or infinitive in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/240449/should-the-verb-try-be-followed-by-gerund-or-infinitive-in-this-sentence) and [Difference between 'try to do' and 'try doing'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226546/difference-between-try-to-do-and-try-doing) also [What is the difference in meaning: "tried singing" vs "tried to sing"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104788/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-tried-singing-vs-tried-to-sing)

Comment: _Try `Verb`-ing_ is fine, but _try to `Verb`_ has a [Gricean implicature of failure](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61558/15299).

Answer (score 0):

With the catenative verb "try", the meaning depends on the kind of subordinate clause functioning as its complement. For example:

> [1] *You should try to eat less.*
>
> [2] *You should try eating less.*

In [1] "try" means "endeavour", while in [2] it means "test the effectiveness of".

Now compare your examples:

> [3] *I tried to order a book on line but I did not succeed.*
>
> [4] *I tried ordering a book on line but I did not succeed.*

[3] is fine where, like in [1], "tried" means "endeavoured". But [4] is wrong since it makes little sense to say that your testing the effectiveness of ordering a book on line did not succeed.

Edited for accuracy and improved clarity.

Comment: I would disagree that there's a difference in meaning here.  Both uses of "tried" here mean "attempted".  I strongly disagree that [2] is "tested the effectiveness of", which is honestly a pretty rare usage of the word "tried".  That definition exists, but surely not in this context... "The horse was tried, but found wanting." would be one such case.  You can see that it doesn't mean this in [2] because the focus changes from "the order" to "me", whereas in my horse example, "the horse" is the focus throughout.

Answer (score -1):

Neither option is really better than the other.  Both are correct grammatically and idiomatically; that is to say, both are commonly used by native speakers.

You could say that "**to order**" puts *slightly* more emphasis on the process of the order itself, while using "**ordering a book**" places *slightly* less emphasis on the process of ordering<sup>1</sup> and so gives *slightly* more emphasis to the failure, but this is a *very* minor thing.  The two sentences are mostly identical in meaning.

<sup>1 - "ordering a book" spreads out the listener's attention to both the order and the book, which slightly de-emphasizes both.</sup>